# Tcl: recursive proc gives "out of stack space"

Tags: list, recursion, tcl

I am a Tcl newbie and for the sake of learning I'm trying to implement a merge sort algorithm pseudo-code from Wikipedia:

```
function merge_sort(list m)
// if list size is 1, consider it sorted and return it
if length(m) <= 1
    return m
// else list size is > 1, so split the list into two sublists
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2
for each x in m before middle
     add x to left
for each x in m after or equal middle
     add x to right
// recursively call merge_sort() to further split each sublist
// until sublist size is 1
left = merge_sort(left)
right = merge_sort(right)
// merge the sublists returned from prior calls to merge_sort()
// and return the resulting merged sublist
return merge(left, right)
```

In my Tcl script I do:

```tcl
proc merge_sort { lst } {

   if { [llength $lst] <= 1 } {
       return $lst
   }

   set middle [expr {[llength $lst] / 2}]

   set left [lrange $lst 0 $middle]
   set right [lrange $lst [expr {$middle + 1}] [llength $lst]]

   set left [merge_sort $left]
   set right [merge_sort $right]

   return [merge $left $right]
}
```

According to my debug attempts, everything works fine until a recursive call of the `merge_sort` proc.

Output says that I am "*out of stack space (infinite loop?)*". Honestly, I don't see a problem in the code. Where am I wrong?

Comment: According to this article http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/lrange.n.html. Command lrange takes list, first and last element. When length of your list == 2, middle = 1, so left contains 0th element and 1th element, and right contains 0 elements. So you got infinte recursion. Debug your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your code uses `[lrange $lst 0 $middle]` to get the left part of the string, but since `lrange`'s range is **zero-based-inclusive** it means that for a two-member list `{7 8}` you would get `middle` equals to `1` and `left` would be `{7 8}`.

Also since you are using `[lrange $lst [expr {$middle + 1}] [llength $lst]]` for `right`, than for the same list it would result in an empty list as `[lrange $lst 2 2]` is empty for a two-member list.

I've also changed the right `lrange` to use `end` as the last index as this is a common best practice instead of `[expr {[llength $lst] - 1}]` which would have been the equivalent.

```
proc merge_sort { lst } {

   if { [llength $lst] <= 1 } {
       return $lst
   }

   set middle [expr {[llength $lst] / 2}]

   #for each x in m *before* middle add x to left
   set left [lrange $lst 0 [expr {$middle - 1}]]

   #for each x in m *after or equal* middle add x to right
   set right [lrange $lst $middle end]

   set left [merge_sort $left]
   set right [merge_sort $right]

   return [merge $left $right]
}
```

Comment: The `{}` are needed to inhibit double interpolation of the Tcl code -- once by the Tcl interpreter itself and another one by the `expr` itself. Apart from making `expr` resilient to certain abuses by user-supplied data (not applicable here), this just makes `expr` go faster as what's in between the `{}` will be compiled once by `expr` and cached in the object holding that string. See [this wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225) for more info.

Comment: A great answer would include some explanatory text as well…

Comment: Thank you @kostix for pointing that out. Good to learn something new after all these years with Tcl. I've reverted this line to the OP's original.